# Is there exist msvs .props analog in cmake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, vsprops

MSVS have a great thing - the .props files. This files gives ability to carry out some project settings in other place. For example, I could write .props for some library, where I set up the include path`s, add .lib files, set up some compiler on linker options, etc. So when I need this library in new project - I just add this .prop file to the project and could immidietelly use this library without any additional project tunning.

So, Is there exist some analog .props in the CMake?

Comment: I guess [project config.cmake](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file) exists for this purpose.

Comment: See [install EXPORT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-exports) and [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html)